# How can I update/remove a local utility?

Tags: plone, zope

I registered a local utility through generic setup and then updated the `__init__` code later. I was surprised to found that the object is not reinitialized when I restart the instance. The utility was just a simple object that subclass the general `object` class.

How can I make the Utility initialize again ?

**Edit: After see Martijn Pieters's explanation I understand that local utility is always persistent. So how can I delete it and then readd it later ?

Comment: Local Utilities are *always* persistent. I prefer to use adapters instead of local utilities for this very reason.

Comment: Thank Martijn, LocalUtility works in my case. The problem is that I updated the Utility code and now wanted to update the object accordingly

Comment: I consider local utilities dangerous as most people don't understand how to correctly use them and they're so difficult to uninstall. You can give http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wildcard.fixpersistentutilities/1.1b4 a try for uninstalling it but be careful in using the package and backup your database first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the comments answered my question already, this is a little sum up so I can close the question:

- Local Utilities are always persistent.
- (Base on my experience) In Plone 4 uninstalling the product won't remove installed Local Utilities by default (I remembered it once did)
- You can user pypi.python.org/pypi/wildcard.fixpersistentutilities/1.1b4 a try for uninstalling Local Utilities.

Thanks Martijn Pieters and vangheem